# How to configure Tomcat connector to use both SSL and TLS protocols?

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, connector

I have a Tomcat 7.0 server that I want to configure to listen on HTTPS port. I'm using Nio protocol and I want it to support both SSLv3 and TLS protocols (I know that SSLv3 is insecure, but I need to provide that ability). Here is how it looks now:

```
<Connector
        port="443"
        SSLEnabled="true"
        clientAuth="false"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        enableLookups="false"
        keyAlias="myalias"
        keystoreFile="mykeystore"
        keystorePass="mypass"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        sslEnabledProtocols="SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

The question is what value should I use as sslProtocol? According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext) SSL enables any SSL protocol, and TLS any TLS protocol, but how to enable both? I tried to set "SSL,TLS" and "SSL_TLS" but these values are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

According to examples in Tomcat 7 SSL/TLS HOWTO, 
[Edit the Tomcat Configuration File](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) the delimiter is `+`:

> ```
> <!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
> <Connector
>            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
>            port="8443" maxThreads="200"
>            scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
>            SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt"
>            SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
>            SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
> ```

Strange this is not in the documentation!

Comment: It should work for APR connector, but Nio fails. I followed this documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html. It says nothing about sslProtocol possible values though. Also I can't replace Nio with Apr at the moment, so I need to find a solution for Nio.